# Migrating Leaderline Annotations from AutoCAD to GDB using FME?

Tags: fme-form, esri-geodatabase, annotation, autocad, leader-line

I am trying to migrate leaderline annotation from AutoCAD to ESRI thru FME. While reading the leader anno from dwg, the reader reads it as 3 individual components and not a single entity.

Is it necessary to define all geodb_text_leader* attributes?

Currently, only the text gets migrated and not the leader line.